# Force background tabs in Chrome to run setTimeout at normal speed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, settimeout, setinterval, chromium

Does Chrome have any manual override of the minimum window timer resolution for background tabs? I'm testing instances of a web application in multiple tabs, and the minimum resolution of 1000 ms interferes with my workflow, forcing me to keep Ctrl+Tabbing through the tabs to keep things running. (The app uses setTimeout to break up long-running operations and preserve  UI responsiveness.)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `webworkers` they timers will remain normal even if tab focus is lost

Comment: Web Workers would introduce a significant performance overhead in simulating something as simple as setTimeout. I'm not looking to change the architecture of my application, just to override Chrome's default settings for the purposes of testing and debugging.